# Where can I post my rough drafts for peer evaluations?

Tags: plot, character-development, fantasy, science-fiction

I apologize if I am not in the right community but I figured this would be the best place to ask.

I am looking for a place or a group where I can have my story read by others, so they can offer me some constructive critisism. What im mostly looking for is for individuals who share the same out look as I do and can provide their own knowledge or beliefs on the subject.

So long story short where can I post chapter 1 of my sci-fi story.

Comment: I agree with @Galastel that this question is a duplicate of the other.  But the other discussion was from 2010-11 and it was locked in 2013.  That's forever in the internet world.  If the other post was allowed then this one is on topic.  And it seems to me to be the sort of thing that is reasonable to reboot now and then.

Comment: Given I can see you're over on [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) as well might I suggest the [Universe Factory chat thread](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27736/universe-factory) as a likely starting point for you.

Comment: @Cyn If you look at the 'Locked' notice on the other question, you'll find: "This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here". Basically, the definition of "on topic" has changed since 2011, but since the question had so much useful information, it was decided not to remove it.

Comment: @Galastel I see that now, thanks.   I absolutely would not count it as a duplicate, as there is no other current thread.  I will say it seems like a currently on topic question to me though...as it's asking for writing resources, which is something we do here, no?  Questions asking for places to find listings/reviews of publishers are allowed...

Comment: @Cyn looks like a good discussion to have in Meta.

Comment: @Galastel please see https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1698/place-for-a-question-asking-for-critique-resources

Comment: Thanks everybody, I haven't been on this site long so I'm still not sure how to look for specifics, I appreciate your help tho.